# "Cannot delete a column that contains controls" Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi

> Project Businessware.exe raised an exception class EGridPanelException with Message "Cannot delete a column that contains controls"

I am always getting this error whenever I tried to execute the program, then it shows an option buttons such as "Break", "Continue" and "Help", I already got this error before and the solution I opted was to delete the ExplicitWidth and ExplicitHeight comprises by the affected component, I also removed ColumnCollection declared under GridPanel1 and everything became alright, but now it is showing again and the solution I applied previously is not working anymore. Do you have any other solution for this?Why am I getting this error when I don't have any updates made in .pas and .dfm file?

Other information is when I clicked "Break", it points out to this method:

```
procedure TColumnCollection.Notify(Item: TCollectionItem; Action: System.Classes.TCollectionNotification);
begin
   inherited;
   if (Action = System.Classes.TCollectionNotification.cnExtracting) 
      and not (csDestroying in Owner.ComponentState) and
      not (csUpdating in Owner.ComponentState) then
        if not Owner.IsColumnEmpty(Item.Index) then
          raise EGridPanelException.Create(sCannotDeleteColumn)
   else
     Owner.UpdateControlsColumn(Item.Index);
end;
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hard to guess without code. Take a look here: [help]

Comment: Thanks, I already added other information in my question. :)

Comment: **42** ... in earnest one of the close vote reasons :
Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code somewhere tries to delete a column of a gridpanel that is not empty (that's what the message says). In order to find out where the error comes from click on break (on the exception dialog) and watch out for your call stack and try to find the first line in the call stack that points to your code, which should show something like this (sorry but I am not allowed to post a picture) :

```
  :7599821fKERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x54
  Vcl.ExtCtrl.TColumnCollection.Notify(???,???)
  ...some more system lines lines here
  MyUnit.MyForm.Button1Click($F73660)    <--- the problem lies in here
```

hth

Comment: It is not necessarily caused by user code. A "corrupt" DFM file of a TForm that contains redundant content from a frame can also cause this: I've had it happen when a TGridPanel's content on a Form did not match the content of a frame.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful To rule out such a problem, it's still useful to look at the call stack, though. If that's the problem, there will be calls to the various classes' `Read*` methods in the call stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my program worked fine now but I don't know why. I forgot to mention that this problem always occurred after `git clone`

Comment: Nearly *9 years later* and the answer suggested by @GünthertheBeautiful is still valid in Delphi 10.1 (Berlin). Simply put, be careful to use frames directly when they contain `GridLayoutPanel`.